# hardcoded security token to login in salesforcesdk android

Tags: salesforce1-app, android, sfdcmobilesdk-android

I am using Salesforce Android SDK. I want to authenticate in the application with my own salesforce email and security token. Is there any way that I can hard code my email and security token in the Salesforce sdk and it wil automatically log in...

Comment: We have done this is iOS SDK. with hardcoded email and security token. I want to implement same in the Android